# streamType differences between devices regarding libraries

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

**Context**

On a web app with all the cast implementation, I launch an stream to a Chromecast dongle so I can watch it. It happens very smoothly and perfect.
But, I want to control the movie usign and Android device so the persistant controls appears on my (i.e) Nexus 5.

**Problem**

The metadata is detected well and the persistant controls shows up perfectly but when tapping on it to see the bigger/fullscreen image/controls, it just crashes and all the app is closed.

Trying the same flow within an iPad, it works perfectly. So we check all the media object received by the receiver and there's a difference between all the devices; the streamType.

The cast_sender.js library send the streamType as "buffered".
Android and iOS send the same string as "BUFFERED".
So, debugging directly on Android, we figure out that sending a non strict streamType causes that crash so, it only works if the streamType is BUFFERED, in uppercase, and the cast_sender.js is sending it in lowercase.

Is there any way to force the web app to send the streamType in upercase? Because we try it within the LoadMedia function but it does nothing (I mean, it breaks the funcionality and nothing happens).

It seems that fixing the cast_sender.js to send the streamType in uppercase may solve this problem...

Comment: Could you please post a piece of log that shows the receiver is sending 'buffered'? And on your chrome sender app what are you setting for streamType?

Comment: Yes, cast_sender.js is sending "buffered" for the media.streamType and iOS/Android send "BUFFERED". This is causing some problems like app crashing in Android when you tap in the persistant controls when you first launched an stream through Chrome.

I fixed this issue by forcing the streamType to be always in uppercase directly in the receiver.